# Set TableView height by the number or rows

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I have got `TableView` in the `MainstoryBoard` and the number of rows is random every time. 
I want the height of the whole `TableView` to be flexible - by that I mean, for example: if I got 4 rows in the `TableView` and each `TableView` row height is 22 so the `TableView` height will be 88. 
Another example:
number of rows: 2
row height = 22
`TableView` will be 44.

How can I make it?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can change the UITableView height as per the contentSize as below:

> Swift 2.2

```
tableView.frame = CGRectMake(tableView.frame.origin.x, tableView.frame.origin.y, tableView.frame.size.width, tableView.contentSize.height)
```

> Swift 3 or 4+

```
tableView.frame = CGRect(x: tableView.frame.origin.x, y: tableView.frame.origin.y, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: tableView.contentSize.height)
```

and make sure you write the above line in `viewDidAppear` method

You need to write the above line in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` also.

> Swift 2.2

```
func viewDidLayoutSubviews(){
     tableView.frame = CGRectMake(tableView.frame.origin.x, tableView.frame.origin.y, tableView.frame.size.width, tableView.contentSize.height)
     tableView.reloadData()
}
```

> Swift 3 or 4+

```
func viewDidLayoutSubviews(){
     tableView.frame = CGRect(x: tableView.frame.origin.x, y: tableView.frame.origin.y, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: tableView.contentSize.height)
     tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Change the UITableView height. for example if i got 2 rows and each row is 22 height so the UITableView height will be 44

Comment: If you want to dynamically change the UITableView height try this, it may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18784741/how-to-dynamically-set-the-height-of-a-uitableview/18784825#18784825

Comment: Sohil, Thank you, it works. but I got another problem - my TableView is in ScrollView so everytime i move the screen (not the tableView) up and down the height of the tableView changes to its default and not to the contentSize.

Comment: @SohilR.Memon Tried it, doesn't work.. (by the way it changed it to override func)

Comment: @SohilR.Memon: How to increase tableView height using Autolayout?

Comment: @Kampai You want to increase the `UITableView` height or `UITableViewCell` height?

Comment: I like to change (increase / decrease) height of table base on numbers of rows, but using auto layout.

Comment: @Kampai Please take the outlet of HeightConstrainst of `UITableView` and change it accordingly using `heightConst.constant = number_of_rows * height of each row`

Comment: I already did these but there are  warnings of unsatisfied constraints. I get the desire height but still constraints not set properly. AnyWay I will post a new question about this scenario soon.

Comment: @Kampai Sure no issue, ping me I will send you the demo of it! Or you can upload your demo Project and I can customize according to your requirement

Comment: @SohilR.Memon: Here is my question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35363292/autolayout-constraints-for-dynamic-table-height-based-on-total-rows

Comment: Worked for me, No need of reload data in `func viewDidLayoutSubviews()`

Comment: Why do we use `frame` and not `bounds`?

Answer (score 5):

Simply take outlet for tableview height constraint and update it in `willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell` method of `UITableView`

```
@IBOutlet weak var tblHConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.tblHConstraint.constant = self.tblView.contentSize.height
    }
```

Comment: worked for Xcode 13.3.1 and iOS 15.4. Thanks, mate.

Answer (score 4):

nothing worked here is the solution i ended up using which gives accurate height.

```
extension UITableView {
    var contentSizeHeight: CGFloat {
        var height = CGFloat(0)
        for section in 0..<numberOfSections {
            height = height + rectForHeader(inSection: section).height
            let rows = numberOfRows(inSection: section)
            for row in 0..<rows {
                height = height + rectForRow(at: IndexPath(row: row, section: section)).height
            }
        }
        return height
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
tableView.contentSizeHeight
```

will give you the actual calculated height of your table view content.

Answer (score 3):

Take outlet of the Height Constraint of the parent view and assign it the height of table view's content + constant(extra height of other contents in the view)

```
heightConstraintView.constant = tableView.contentSize.height + constantValue //use the value of constant as required.
```

and write this code in the cellForRowAt method.

Comment: This seems like a better answer to me Mr. Memon's. Any time I am setting a frame in modern iOS I feel like I am doing something wrong. Maybe cellForRow is not the best place for it - certainly it's somewhere that would be reliable called though.

Comment: It works, but if the tableview has 20 cells, there are all initialized at a time, there is no lazy loading... how to achieve this?

Comment: I have to do it in DispatchQueue.main.async block, then it worked . Thanks

Answer (score 3):

To use with with autolayout:

Somewhere in `viewDidLoad()`

```
tableView.anchor(top: view.topAnchor, leading: view.leadingAnchor, bottom: nil, trailing: view.trailingAnchor)
```

and then in your `viewDidLayoutSubViews()`

```
tableView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: tableView.contentSize.height).isActive = true
```

Comment: Why this is not a best answer? You saved my day!

Comment: Thanks man. i set the top,trailing,leading in storyboard and height in code. Worked for me

Answer (score 2):

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    var frame = tableView.frame
    frame.size.height = tableView.contentSize.height
    tableView.frame = frame
}
```

OR

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.TblViewHeightConstraint.constant = CGFloat((self.array.count) * 30)//Here 30 is my cell height
    self.TblView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: How can I get cell height instead setting it static as 30?

Answer (score 1):

Please find the below code.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UIScreen.main.bounds.height
}
        
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    let tableViewHeight = self.tableView.frame.height
    let contentHeight = self.tableView.contentSize.height
            
    let centeringInset = (tableViewHeight - contentHeight) / 2.0
    let topInset = max(centeringInset, 0.0)
            
    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: topInset, left: 0.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this for Swift 3

```
 override func viewDidLayoutSubviews(){
    tableView.frame = CGRect(x: tableView.frame.origin.x, y:  tableView.frame.origin.y, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: tableView.contentSize.height)
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: im confuse... why do you update the frame before loading the data?

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** when your are increasing the tableview height it will goes out side the view. and you will get a problem with scrolling.

Ex: take a view inside that keep tableview and give constraints to left,right,bottom,top to Zero(0).

now reload the tableview assume  2 rows each row height is 20 now total rows height is 40. its fine and gave those height to table view, Table view will show only 40 height (you can assign tableview height by taking constraints (or) table view content size both are give same height according to rows height).

But if you reload 50 rows you will get scrolling problem because those rows height given to table view height, here table view height expands more than your screen height.

To solve this problem you should use scroll view outside the tableview.

Answer (score 0):

Take outlet of tableview height and set it with your tableview row height in cellForRowAt like this,

tableviewHeight.constant = (tableView.contentSize.height * no_of_rows) + bottom_space