# UITableView dynamic content size height inside UIScrollView with AutoLayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, autolayout

I have a `UIScrollView`, inside this `UIScrollView` I have a `UIView` and inside the `UIView` I have some `UITextField's`, some `UILabel's` and at the bottom there is a `UITableView`.

I want the `UITableView` to fit it's content height, the `UIView` to fit it's content height and the `UIScrollView` to fit it's content height.

The `UITableView` height might change as I add / remove cells from it during usage.

What is the best way to handle it using **`AutoLayout`**?

```
- UIViewController
-- UIView
--- UIScrollView
---- UIView
----- UILabel
----- UITextField
----- UITextView
----- UITableView (at the bottom of the superview)
```

or as in the xib:

[image]

Comment: You should generally not nest scroll views. There lies madness. Rather think about implementing a tableview-like view without a scrollview if you intend to show all of it anyways.

Comment: I'm going to show all of it anyways, that's true, BUT, it should be cells because there are rows that will be added and removed by the user dynamically and the best way to handle this situation is by using UITableView.

Comment: Just use a table view. It is a scroll view anyway and it can contain all the stuff that you're putting into the scroll view. No need for the additional scroll view. Just use a single table view.

Comment: @Fogmeister is right, There is no rocket science, Just try it. It looks tuff at first but it is easy to implement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to implement this is to scrap the hierarchy that you have now and do the following...

```
- UIViewController (or UITableViewController)
--- UITableView
----- UIView (as the tableView.tableHeaderView)
------- UILabel
------- UITextField
------- UITextView
----- Rest of the cells for the table view.
```

The `tableView.tableHeaderView` is a single (not reusable, concrete) view that is placed at the top of the content of the table view and scrolls with the content of the table view. It doesn't stick to the top of the screen like a section header view does.

This will allow you to delete the scroll view and place everything inside the table view and still doesn't change the methods that you are using to populate the cells as that remains untouched.

Comment: That's exactly what I thought at this moment! great answer man!

Answer (score 1):

@Jan Greve is correct. But if you still want to do it

1. Set Bottom Space to Container constraint between the Table View and its super view to 0
2. Increase/decrease the height constraint of the Table View with each insert/delete (You will have to do this programmatically)
3. Set the content offset of the scrollview to the new view height

Answer (score 1):

The best part of **AutoLayout** is now you don't have to worry about `UIScrollView` content size.

If you set all constraints properly(without any warnings) AutoLayout manage content size for scrollView itself.

Set all subview's constraints but don't add `height` and `width` constraints.

And for `contentSize` add **bottom** constraint of inner view (subview of scrollview) to `UIScrollView`. This will increaser `scrollView` content size and height as per inner view expand or shrink.

**For more details**: I asked [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35363292/autolayout-constraints-for-dynamic-table-height-based-on-total-rows) for same, you can check it. You can find code in question itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a fixed height to the tableView and link the constraint to an outlet. Then you'd need to override viewDidLayoutSubviews() in order to set the height dynamically based on the contentSize of the table:

```
@IBOutlet weak var dynamicTVHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!

internal override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    let height = min(self.view.bounds.size.height, self.tableView.contentSize.height)
    self.dynamicTVHeight.constant = height
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```